# Trying to run sh script and getting docker-compose not installed error?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run a shell script to check if docker-compose is installed. I do so by running this code in a .sh file and running `sudo ./xyz.sh` on the cli:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! [[ -x "$(command -v docker-compose)" ]]; then
  echo 'Error: docker-compose is not installed.' >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

When I run docker-compose --version from command line i get back: docker-compose version 1.24.0, build 0aa59064

`which docker-compose` gives me /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

My server is Linux version 4.14.171-105.231.amzn1.x86_64 (mockbuild@koji-pdx-corp-builder-64005) (gcc version 7.2.1 20170915 (Red Hat 7.2.1-2) (GCC)) #1 SMP Thu Feb 27 23:49:15 UTC 2020

Any ideas on what is wrong here?

Comment: That would indicate that the sudo/root environment does not include /usr/local/bin in the path.

Comment: wow, didn't even think of that. This is the issue, thanks